# Why am I getting ERR_CONNECTION_RESET when trying to access Parallels Windows localhost from Mac?

Tags: port-forwarding, parallels

I have created a port forwarding rule with source and destination port 8081 using TCP and forward to Windows 10 and turned off the firewall on Windows domain network and public network. I start an emulator on Windows running on said port, but when trying to access localhost:8080 on mac, I only get "This site can’t be reached The connection was reset". Anybody who has experienced the same?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a connection fall
Ti maybe caused by a firewall
Try reinstalling the software

Or Try to check in internet